# Pure constructors in class templates

Tags: d

I have some code that works, and I'm not sure why. I'm instantiating a class as an immutable variable. There are no `immutable` constructors in the class and none are labeled as `pure`, but it just works anyway.

I also read that `pure` constructors can be used across the board for mutable, immutable, const, and shared instances

The only thing I can find on the D website is that purity is inferred in function templates. Should I assume that since my class is parameterized (or a class template) that the compiler is inferring the purity of all the methods, including the constructor?

Code below:

```
public class Data(size_t numInputs, size_t numTargets)
{
  ...
  public this(in double[][] data, in bool[] filter, in bool doNorm = true)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only thing I can find on the D website is that purity is inferred in function templates. Should I assume that since my class is parameterized (or a class template) that the compiler is inferring the purity of all the methods, including the constructor?

Yes. Since the class is a template, all the methods are also templates (consider that they have to be since the hidden `this` parameter's type comes from the template). Thus, their body must be available in the source. The two requirements for inferred attributes are body source available and a template parameter for them (and also the function must not try to call or inspect itself, but you don't do that either) thus it can be inferred as pure.